# Select all where first letter begins with 'a%' or 'b%' or 'c%' or 'f%' etc...in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I understand that `OR (||)` can be used multiple times, but is there a shorter code for this? When I use `IN`,
it doesn't give the right answer.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? It's not completely clear.

Comment: @Nick I have several strings in a column and I want to print all the strings that begin with specific characters.
select * from books where author_lname like 'c%' || author_lname like 's%' so on and so forth.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch why did you delete your answer, it was a good one?

Comment: @Nick for me good answers are correct and accepted answers. I undelete it and extend with alternatives. There are so many ways to solve this. I personally would use the `LEFT` and `LOWER`, but your solution using `REGEXP` is better (I guess in performance too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regexp to match the first character. Just add the characters you want to match at the start of the name to the set inside the `[]`:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE author_lname REGEXP '^[abcf]'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=285892f77dbbac7977de218ce09b03ad)

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions with RLIKE

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE author_lname RLIKE '^[a-f]';
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution using [`LEFT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) with `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE LEFT(author_lname, 1) IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'f')
```

To check case insensitive you can use the following, using [`LOWER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower):

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE LOWER(LEFT(author_lname, 1)) IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'f')
```

You can also use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * 
FROM books
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(LOWER(LEFT(author_lname, 1)), 'a,b,c,f') > 0
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ecf38b32a84f13b3ece5378b9b42aca)

Comment: Would @volodymyr method of RLIKE work faster or the IN function given by you?

Comment: The best answer isn't always the accepted one. I'm not sure which would be faster out of these and the regexp ones or even @forpas' answer but you have offered 3 good alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get the result you want and one of them is this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 'abcf' LIKE CONCAT('%', LEFT(mycolumn, 1), '%')
```